# Automapper with nested child list

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, automapper, automapper-2

I have two classes below:

```
public class Module
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ImageName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Page> Pages { get; set; }
}

public class ModuleUI
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    public List<PageUI> PageUIs { get; set; }
}
```

The mapping must be like this:

```
Id -> Id
Name -> Text
ImageName -> ImagePath 
Pages -> PageUIs
```

How can I do this using Automapper?

Comment: Without AutoMapper you could write: `new ModuleUI {Id = module.Id, ImagePath = module.ImageName, PageUIs = new List<PageUI>(module.Pages.Cast<PageUI>())};`

Comment: Sorry for posting this as an answer, I would prefer to put it as a comment on the solution but due to reputation lower than 50, I couldn't. The elected solution works just fine, and thanks for it! But I keep thinking about one thing: I usually separate the mappings on several profiles, by entity, let's say.
So here I would have a ModuleProfile with the Module to ModuleUI mapping settings and a PageProfile with the Page to PageUI mapping settings. On this scenario, how would you do it? Would you still include the - Mapper.CreateMap<Page, PageUI>(); - on the ModuleProfile?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can use `ForMember` and `MapFrom` ([documentation](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Projection)).
Your Mapper configuration could be:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Module, ModuleUI>()
    .ForMember(s => s.Text, c => c.MapFrom(m => m.Name))
    .ForMember(s => s.ImagePath, c => c.MapFrom(m => m.ImageName))
    .ForMember(s => s.PageUIs, c => c.MapFrom(m => m.Pages));
Mapper.CreateMap<Page, PageUI>();
```

Usage:

```
var dest = Mapper.Map<ModuleUI>(
    new Module
    {
        Name = "sds",
        Id = 2,
        ImageName = "sds",
        Pages = new List<Page>
        {
            new Page(), 
            new Page()
        }
    });
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Yes! AutoMapper threats null values and works for me too!

Comment: Thanks!

This answer is still valid after so much years.